# Initializer block inside the main method?

Tags: java

I know a little about initialization blocks that are used in classes. But i came across this question:

```
 //What is the output of the following program?

 public class Test {
    private static int i = 0;
    private static int j = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 2;
        int k = 3;

        // What is this thing, that appears to be like an initializer block inside the main method?
        {
            int j = 3;
            System.out.println("i + j is " + i + j);
        }

        k = i + j;

        System.out.println("k is " + k);
        System.out.println("j is " + j);
    }
}
```

My question is: **What is this thing, that appears to be like an initializer block inside the main method?**

Comment: it's used to define a scope. Variables declared inside the block will be unknown outside the block. So j cannot be used outside the block.

Comment: its just a block and `int j=3;` is local to it this `j=3` isn't accessible outside which is shown by value of `k.`

Comment: The block is localising the scope of the variable `j`. Inside the block, `j` refers to the variable declared `int j = 3;`. Outside the block, `j` refers to the static field declared `int j = 0;`. Other than to localise variables, the braces here don't have any effect.

Comment: Note that the `j` inside the block is *shadowing* (inside the block) the `public static int j` variable.

Comment: That is why `k` is 2 in the end

Comment: It is not an initializer block, it is simply a block - a construct for delineating a new scope, and grouping statements together.

Comment: Is this homework? Just so we don’t do it for you in our helpfulness.

Comment: Okay now i get it. I was confused because i was just learning about initializer blocks and then i saw this. Thanks !

Comment: @OleV.V. No its not homework. It's just exercises at the end of the chapter.

Comment: How is it NOT an Instance Initializer block? @SergeyKalinichenko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the comments for others who stumble across this question:
the `{}` is a block that defines scope. In this particular example the value of `j` inside the block will be 3. However outside the block would be zero. That would cause different results of the additions.

Also note that this statement `System.out.println("i + j is " + i + j);` would just print

> "i + j is 23"

and not

> "i + j is 5"

This is because the `+` operator would just convert all the ints to their string representation and append them.
If you do want to have the sum it statement should actually be:
`System.out.println("i + j is " + (i + j));`

Answer (score 4):

*[This answer is addressed to a wider novice audience]*

Within a method, a set of declarations and statements enclosed with `{ }` braces is a ***compound statement***, also called a ***block statement*** or simply a ***block***. It creates a new scope nested within the current scope within a method body.

This is used all of the time in constructs that require more than one statement to be executed as a unit. E.g.:

```
if (a > b)
{                   // Block
    int tmp = a;    // 'tmp' is local to this block
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

The block syntax may appear unusual, however, when used by itself without a *controlling statement*:

```
// Bare block with no controlling if/else/for/while/do/switch
{
    int t = frob(b);
    b = frob(a);
    a = flub(t, a);
}
```

This kind of thing is typically done to isolate a complicated chunk of code within its own scope, especially if it uses a lot of local variables that are not needed anywhere else within the parent method.

This syntax can be over-used, of course:

```
void froodle(int a, int b)
{{
    if (a < 0  ||  a < b)
    {{
        frob(-a, b);
        frob(b, 0);
    }}
}}
```

While the `{{ }}` double braces look unusual, they simply define a block nested within another block. In code above, the entire method body contains a single statement, which is itself a block. For clarity, this can be rewritten as:

```
void froodle(int a, int b)
{
    {
        if (a < 0  ||  a < b)
        {
            {
                frob(-a, b);
                frob(b, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The block syntax is a special case when it appears within a class definition but *not* within a method body. In these cases, it is a *class initializer*, i.e., a block of code that is executed when the class is first loaded and initialized. It is as if the block is the body of a special unnamed function that gets executed at class loading time.

```
class Bar
{
    static Foo  myFoo;

    // Class initializer
    static
    {
        myFoo = new Foo(100);
        myFoo.freeble(200);
    }

    ...
}
```

**Addendum**

Note that the class initialization block requires a `static` keyword preceding it (which I added to the example code above). Note also that the code can only access `static` members and methods in the class.